# Dynamic Data Entities across multiple databases

Tags: asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm looking at building a quick administrative backend that services several databases. The databases are not connected to each other, but I'd like to be able to manage things in one place. Is it possible to do this in the latest version of ASP.NET dynamic data entities? If so, how painful is it? What I'm really looking for is a way to have routes for each database. So, for instance, I'd want /App1/Customers to go to the customers table in the app1 database and /app2/Locations to go to the locations table in the app2 database. Is there some way to rig something like this?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is you just need to add multiple models David Ebbo has an article here [Using Dynamic Data with multiple databases](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2008/12/11/using-dynamic-data-with-multiple-databases.aspx) if you are using EF6 there will be changes to this method.

Comment: That link is dead. If you can find the content please update this answer. If you can explain the answer that would help us avoid link rot. Do either and tag me so I can undo the downvote.

Comment: David Ebbo must have deleted his old blog :(

Comment: I don't think _he_ did it. It probably got swept up by another Microsoft digital bookburning - uh, I mean "archiving".